# Как вынести $(this) для обработчика клика в другую функцию? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, есть такой код:

```
$(document).on('click', '.container', function(){
  $(this).css('top', '1px');
})
```

Как можно вынести обработку клика в другую функцию? Например что бы получилось так:

```
function clickHeandler(){
  $(this).css('top', '1px');
}
$(document).on('click', '.container', function(){
  clickHeandler();
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

```
function clickHeandler(){
  $(this).css('top', '1px');
}

$(document).on('click', '.container', function(){
  clickHeandler.call(this);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант

```
function clickHandler() {
  $(this).css('top', '1px');
}
$(document).on('click', '.container', clickHandler);
```

Просто выносим обработчик в отдельную функцию (и не оборачиваем её дополнительной `function() { ... }`)